# Best log file monitoring tool for ubuntu server

Tags: server, software-recommendation, monitoring, log

I'm trying to find the best Log File monitoring tool for Ubuntu 9.10 server?

Is there any web-based gui tool which could be operated by anyone, that monitor any log files?

I already tried splunk and felt it's a bit hard to operate and it's not a completely free tool

Comment: Would be helpful to know more - free or commercial, purpose of monitoring, examples of logs to be monitored, alerting requirements, storage requirements, number of servers, etc.

Comment: Which questions do you need to have answered by this tool?

Comment: Still no information provided.  Marking this question down.  Answers are being marked down without explanation too.  Pretty poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a demo of this tool, called [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/view/free-vs-enterprise/SP-CAAAE8W), at Infosec this year.  It looks pretty incredible - a viable alternative to tools like LogLogic and LogRhythm.

Comment: I already tried splunk and felt it's a bit hard to operate and it's not free one.

Comment: Add this to your question, along with the other information I queried in my comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Splunk is great for log analysis and event identification, http://code.google.com/p/logstash/ has a web ui and can aggregate multiple servers logs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it yet. Give it a try. http://planetit.ws/linux/ubuntu/install-centralized-syslog-server-with-web-interface.html