# How to trace all the file transfered into my ubuntu server

Tags: monitoring, scp, traffic

I just started a task and I'm trying to get a list of the all file transfer that is happening on my server, from outside the server, mean user sending file through ftp or scp just,

This task is just for a periodically health check,

I read here that the scp file transfer log file i the same as ssh, I tried to serch inside this file `/var/log/auth.log` using

```
grep -i "scp" /var/log/auth.log
```

but I found nothing. the return was empty.

does anyone have any idea how that should happened or should I turn some feature on to log that information for future file transfer?

Thanks!

Comment: Try searching in `auth.log.1`: `grep ssh /var/log/auth.log.1`

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! highly appreciated! I got a list for ssh connections that happened on the server, can I get a list of the files name and maybe the location from where they has been sent.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19518/best-log-file-monitoring-tool-for-ubuntu-server

Comment: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/monitoring-real-time-user-logins-in-ubuntu.html